# Show that this relation is true

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

If you have 3 scores and you look at the sum of the scores > 45 (GT), the sum of the scores < 45 (LT) and the total sum of scores (TS) this relation holds:

$$1-\left(\frac{LT}{TS}\right) = 0.5\left[\frac{TS+GT-LT}{TS}\right]$$

For example if you have 3 scores 10, 50 and 60. The sum of scores $> 45$ i.e. $GT = 110$ and the sum of scores less than 45 i.e. $LT = 10$ and the total sum of scores = 120.

```
score   Sum >45  Sum  <45
        10       0         10
        50       50         0
        60       60         0     
Total  120      110        10
```

$1-(LT/TS) = .5*[(TS+GT-LT)/TS]$

i.e.

```
1-(10/120) = .5*[(120+110-10)/120]  
= .91= .91
```

but can you do the algebra to show that will hold no matter what value the score is

```
1-(LT/TS) = .5*[(TS+GT-LT)/TS]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1-\left(\frac{LT}{TS}\right) = 0.5\left[\frac{TS+GT-LT}{TS}\right]$

$1=\frac{TS}{TS}$. The LHS becomes

$\frac{TS}{TS}-\frac{LT}{TS}=\frac{TS-LT}{TS}$

And $GT=TS-LT$. The RHS becomes

$0.5\left[\frac{TS+(TS-LT)-LT}{TS}\right]=0.5\left[\frac{2TS-2LT}{TS}\right]$

You can multiply out the brackets on the RHS. Then you can multiply the equation   by $TS$ and the denominators disappear. And finally add $LT$ and substract $TS$ on both sides of the equation. The equation becomes $0=0$. This is always true.